# Как исключить отправку пустой строки и сделать подсчёт оставшихся для ввода знаков в поле input?

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, form

Есть такая форма:

```
<form>
<p>Введите телефон :</p>
<p><input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{12}"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
```

Работает корректно, кроме случая, когда отправляешь пустую строку. Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы учитывалась и пустая строка?

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы пользователь видел сколько символов осталось вбить?

Comment: Добавить инпуту `required`. Тогда не получится просто пропустить это поле, а дальше надо вводить по шаблону.

Comment: Истину глаголят про `required`. Но проверка браузером недостаточно гибкая.

Comment: @notatrueprogrammer, нельзя доверять клиенту, это легко убрать на стороне браузера и все ваши проверки на стороне клиент-части будут бесполезными. Исключить пустую строку без валидации на стороне сервера, не получится.

Comment: @And, `pattern` использовать тоже не стоит, но я не знаю, что в данном случае на бэкенде, чтобы подсказать проверку.

Comment: @notatrueprogrammer, Серьёзно? А UI, UX и другие крутые штуки?

Comment: @notatrueprogrammer, ничего не нужно делать, так как он хочет, чтобы и пустая строка тоже проходила. Ему нужно лишь `maxlength` и события `keyboard` - для того, чтобы отслеживать ввод и рассчитывать оставшиеся символы в `input` - но опять-же, минуя сервер - это делать бесполезно, если на сервере не будет проверки типо 10 < `mb_strlen` и проверка через тот-же `preg_match` - его патерна, то можно будет отправить что, угодно, убрав аттрибуты у `input`.

Comment: Откуда эта идея во всех рождается, что если есть валидация, то она должна быть супер жесткой, сразу задействовать сервер, не дай бог на клиенте что-то подменят ... да нет такого, хочешь валидировать телефон - подключай смс с кодом подтверждения, хочешь валидировать емэил, отправляй письмо со ссылкой подтверждения ... это софт валидейшен, чисто что бы намекнуть человеку, что он что-то делает совсем не так. Не так часто встречается кейс, когда какое-то поле требует супер валидации ещё и без возможности подмены на уровне клиента.

Comment: Проверка на стороне сервера стоит. Просто не хочется лишнего обращения к серверу, когда люди часто сперва нажимают кнопку, а потом уже проверяют что они недописали и т.д. Спасибо за советы, принял к сведению )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Атрибут `required`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea/required) устанавливает текстовое поле обязательным для заполнения перед отправкой формы на сервер. Если в обязательном поле нет текста, обозреватель сети выведет сообщение, а форма отправлена не будет. Вид и содержание сообщения зависит от обозревателя сети и меняться пользователем не может.

Подсчёт оставшихся цифр только через `JavaScript`:

```js
document.querySelector('#tel').onkeyup = function(e) {
  var length = 12;
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'Осталось ввести ' + (length - this.value.length) + ' цифр.';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Введите телефон:</p>
  <p><input type="tel" id="tel" maxlength="12" placeholder="007908123456" pattern="[0-9]{12}" required>
    <br><span id="output"></span></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```